# WPF - Binding two lists to datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Hello I would like binding list of this object to datagrid:

```
class DataGridRows
{
  public int Number{get; set;}
  public int Avg {get; set;}
  public List<Item> Items{get; set;}
}

class Item
{
  public int Number{get; set;}
  public int Avg {get; set;}
}
```

And XAML is:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridRows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Avg}" FontSize="10"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}" FontSize="10"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Items.Avg}" Header="{Binding Items.Number}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

This is not correct. Dont show data from inner list.

Comment: `Items.Avg` is incorrect binding path. `Items[0].Avg` and `Items[0].Number` should display 1st item data. if you need *all* items data you'd better use Template column

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know how to use it. Please show me that?

Comment: Could you post your ViewModel? What is the DataGrid DataContext?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource binding has no effect. There is no data flow from source to target property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Give the List<> Items as the ItemsSource. Since the list contains objects of Item, you can bind the properties of the Item class to the datagrid.

C#

```
class DataGridRows
{
    public List<Item> Items{get; set;}
}

class Item
{
  public int Number{get; set;}
  public int Avg {get; set;}
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="230"   Header="Header Text" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" >
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="230"   Header="Header Text" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" >
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
          <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Avg}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You can easily use a DataGridTemplate like this.

Comment: You are supposing that DataGridRows is his DataGrid DataContext

Comment: Thanks, but my DataContext is list of DataGridRows. My Table must look like this:
Line1: `DataGridRows.Number|DataGridRows.Avg|DataGridRows.Items[0].Number|DataGridRows.Items[0].Avg`

Line2:
`DataGridRows.Number|DataGridRows.Avg|DataGridRows.Items[1].Number|DataGridRows.Items[1].Avg`
Properties Number and Avg from DataGridRows are as title of row and in Items are values.